# Sweetalert now showing values and two buttons for prompts

Tags: sweetalert, sweetalert2

I am trying to customize the swal prompt code. What I am trying to do is get the value from input then send it to the server for processing. After I click the Update Button nothing happens! I am not able to understand why is it happening so. Also, I am trying to implement the cancel button in it but it doesn't seem to work either, look like it only accept one button there.

Following is my code.

```
$(".edit").click(function(event)
        {
            var id = $(this).data("id");
            var $this = $(this);

            var value = $(this).closest('td').prev('td').text();

            swal("Edit The Category Name as Per Your Need Dude!", {
                    content: {
                                element: "input",
                                attributes: {
                                  placeholder: "Enter Your Desired Category Name",
                                  value: value,
                                },
                              },
                    buttons: {
                          cancel: {
                            text: "cancel",
                            value: true,
                            visible: true,
                            className: "btn-primary",
                            closeModal: true
                        },
                        confirm: {
                            text: "Update Name!",
                            value: true,
                            visible: true,
                            className: "btn-success",
                            closeModal: false
                        }
                    }
                })
                .then((value) => {
                    if(value != "")
                        {
                            swal(`You typed: ${value}`);
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            if (value === false) return false;

                            if (value === "")
                                {
                                    swal("You need to write something!", "", "error");
                                    return false;
                                }
                        }
                })
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement it using sweetAlert2, then you are using the wrong syntax for `swal`. You can have a look at the full documentation and examples at https://sweetalert2.github.io/.

If I understood correctly what you want to implement, this is a possible implementation using sweetAlert2:

```
swal({
  title: 'Edit The Category Name as Per Your Need Dude!', 
  input: 'text', 
  inputAttributes: {
    placeholder: "Enter Your Desired Category Name",
    value: 'value',
  },
  showCancelButton: true, 
  confirmButtonText: 'Update Name!', 
  inputValidator: (value) => {
    return !value && 'You need to write something!'
  } 
})
.then((result) => {
  if(result.value) {
    swal(`You typed: ${result.value}`);
  } 
})
```

You can see a running example of the code above at https://materialistic-hen.glitch.me/

Comment: Would you mind explaning what is not working for you? The example at the link at the end of my answer works fine for me. If it’s not what you need maybe you can explain your requirements.